# Replacing PHP with version from another repo

Tags: php, yum, plesk

I made a HUGE mistake a while ago and installed/enabled the remi repo to upgrade php. This has caused issues in our CRM package. I would like to be able to return to the previously installed php from atomic.
I have tried executing:

```
yum remove --nodeps php.x86_64 php-cli.x86_64 php-common.x86_64 php-devel.x86_64 php-gd.x86_64 php-imap.x86_64 php-ldap.x86_64 php-mbstring.x86_64 php-mcrypt.x86_64 php-mysqlnd.x86_64 php-pdo.x86_64 php-pear.noarch php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 php-pecl-jsonc-devel.x86_64 php-pecl-zip.x86_64 php-process.x86_64 php-tidy.x86_64 php-xml.x86_64
```

This comes back with dependencies to be removed (which I assume will break Plesk):

```
    Removing for dependencies:
 php-ioncube-loader
                 x86_64 1:4.7.1-4.el6.art             @atomic             7.3 M
 psa-horde       noarch 5.2.6-cos6.build1205150821.14 @PLESK_12_5_30-dist  66 M
 psa-imp         noarch 6.2.9-cos6.build1205150819.14 @PLESK_12_5_30-dist  18 M
 psa-ingo        noarch 3.2.5-cos6.build1205150819.14 @PLESK_12_5_30-dist 4.5 M
 psa-kronolith   noarch 4.2.8-cos6.build1205150819.14 @PLESK_12_5_30-dist 8.8 M
 psa-mnemo       noarch 4.2.6-cos6.build1205150819.14 @PLESK_12_5_30-dist 3.3 M
 psa-passwd      noarch 5.0.2-cos6.build1205150819.14 @PLESK_12_5_30-dist 2.9 M
 psa-php5-configurator
                 x86_64 1.7.0-cos6.build1205150820.19 @PLESK_12_5_30-dist  54 k
 psa-turba       noarch 4.2.7-cos6.build1205150819.14 @PLESK_12_5_30-dist 6.2 M
```

I have researched alternative methods to remove these packages including the --nodeps option in rpm. But I'm not willing to further break the system.
I have tried downgrade, reinstall and further researched yum shell. I'm at a loss.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: I have huge doubts this is related to "remi" repository, rather to version choosen. BTW, plesk server sARE NOT centos (too much altered)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `yum history` command. It shows your couple last `yum` commands and you cold revert command when installed PHP from Remi repo by command `yum history undo <ID>`.